# Why textboxes loses its masking capability on postback?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, jquery-plugins, masking

I have applied jquery function for masking text boxes in asp.net. It works fine until I post back. On postback it loses its masking capability. Why ?

```
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/datatables/dynamic/docs/media/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="../assets/global/plugins/input-mask/dist/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
```

then

```
<script>
      jQuery(function ($) {
            $("#txtBoxNICNo").mask("99999-9999999-9", { placeholder: "" });
            $("#txtBoxPhoneOffice").mask("+99-99-9999999", { placeholder: "" });
            $("#txtBoxPhoneResidence").mask("+99-99-9999999", { placeholder: "" });
            $("#txtBoxMobile").mask("+99-999-9999999", { placeholder: "" });
        });
and for instance:
</script>

 <asp:TextBox ID="txtBoxNICNo" runat="server" onkeypress="return isNumberKeyCNIC(this)" ClientIDMode="Static" placeholder="XXXXX-XXXXXXX-X" MaxLength="15" CssClass="form-control"></asp:TextBox>
```

Comment: you mean to say --- the placeholder text gets _disappears_ whenever a postback happens ?

Comment: Are you using update panel?

Comment: yes Updatepanel and the masking sequence get disappeared

Comment: And your text boxes are out side update panel

Comment: no sir they are inside the update panel